# Simulate hardwarwe buttons WP7

Tags: button, windows-phone-7, hardware, simulate

i try to Simulate the hardware buttons of the Windows phone.
For example, i want to simulate the case when i tap on the screen the phone should react like i tapped on the power button. so my expection for this case is that the phone lock the screen.

Is that possible?

Thanks&regards!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Your code cannot "simulate" the phone's hardware buttons neither can it invoke functions like power off, lock screen.